# Is it possible to reboot every 3 hours and also execute a script every 6 hours using Cron?

Tags: linux, bash, cron, openwrt

Basically, this is my crontab

```
0 */3 * * * sleep 70 && touch /etc/banner && reboot
10 */6 * * * /root/updater
```

The first does a reboot and the second does an update.  I want to check for updates every six hours, but reboot every 3 hours.  I want them both to be independent.

I gave an offset of 10 minutes to the update script thinking it might compensate for the reboot time.  Reboot time is about a minute on my Linux board.

Comment: "reboot every 3 hours" The need to do this is usually an indication that something is very broken.

Comment: Its an embedded board with openwrt distro.  It needs a reboot to free some memory and any other temporary cache clutter.

Comment: Both symptoms of something broken.

Comment: Don't run multiple commands on one line, just use sh script to do what you need to do. Also, you should include the user that the script should be executed under.

Comment: ... and what is the question exactly?

Comment: Last time I rebooted was 2014 -  Why so often?